# WCF client (Add Service Reference) hates WebGet and WebInvoke...really, it does

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, json, platform-agnostic

I have been working to create WCF services that will operate independent of .Net clients.  Thanks to Google and StackOverflow, I have been able to create both simple xml and json services without Soap wrappers and a bunch of fancy WCF stuff that I just don't need.  It has been a painful experience, hence the subject line of this question.  WCF is mad buggy on the client side when using WebGet and WebInvoke when automatically adding the service reference.

To inspect the communication, I've been creating a WCF client locally and passing everything through [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  That way, whether it works or not, I can at least see what the client is trying to send.  And when it finally does work, I can see the data being sent from both ends and then duplicate this communication in a non-.Net client.

My current problem is that when I change the service to expect POST data as json (enableWebScript behavior), the client has no idea, and it still tries to send the objects as xml.  I've had a ton of issues with the client's config not automatically being set properly when using Add Service Reference, so I'm hoping it's something simple I can add to the app.config on the client.  When using XML, the objects I create and use in the service are automatically xml serialized by the client (which is most convenient).  Is that even possible to do as json in the current version of WCF?

It should be noted that I was able to figure out what I need to do manually and get it to work in a raw form with Fiddler (request builder), so I can serialize my objects in code and send the data manually via http post...that's how I'm doing it in my non-.Net clients anyway.  This is more of a question to understand the WCF aspects better and why I'm missing so many attributes on the client side where there's little to no documentation available to address the issues.

Comment: Man.. I wish I would have read this earlier. We've gone through basically the exact same thought process. I expected the REST client to "just work" like the SOAP client does.

Comment: Are you tied to WCF or do you have the option of server/service payload technology?  Since posting this over two years ago, I have resisted using WCF for anything.  Every service I create or consume manually builds lightweight xml and/or json data, and I roll my own security and anything else that WCF tried to make more convenient for the dev.  I think it's pretty telling that it's practically impossible to find a popular public web api exposed as a WCF service

Comment: No, we aren't tied to WCF but I think we might try it for one of our services. Building the server-side components using WCF was painful until we understood everything. Although... it was nice not having to build the endpoints by hand (we got SOAP/REST/JSON all working). Now, I realize we'll just use SOAP if we're using a .NET client and let others consume REST/JSON.

Answer (score 3):

WCF service references are for RPC payloads that are self-describing - i.e. SOAP, wsHttp etc.  Equally WCF strongly-typed clients are only intended to work with the RPC payloads because only they are capable of broadcasting all the type information etc required for it to work correctly.

When you use webget and webinvoke you are creating non-rpc services (intended to write REST services) which are also not self-describing and therefore it's not ideally suited for the service reference functionality.

You can of course write a .Net client for this - but you'll find it a lot easier to write it using WebClient/WebRequest, manually formatting/reading the XML/Json requests/responses (or use DataContractSerializer and DataContractJsonSerializer to help out with that).

Answer (score 1):

SOAP is self-describing (through a WSDL).

WebGet/WebInvoke do not expose any metadata that would tell the client to use JSON instead of XML.